# Handling device input and focus in UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

I've been recently looking into to game development and got my hands on Microsofts XNA4.0 (Monogame respectively). Unfortunately, XNA doesn't really ship with a UI toolkit so I started writing one myself (I know there are a lot of 3rd party toolkits out there, but for educational purposes I decided to re-invent the wheel).

My question is: How do UI frameworks manage  and orchestrate device input, especially regarding to focus? Let's say I've got an event-driven abstraction over a physical keyboard which state is polled using a simple loop:

```
public interface IKeyboard {
    event EventHandler<Keys> KeyPressed;
    void Update();
}
```

Every control which can process key-strokes needs access to that provider so it will be notified when a 'KeyPressed' event occurs. The thing is: When I have 10 textboxes on the screen and everyone is listening for inputs, on a key-stroke every textbox writes the input, even if it's not on focus.

Possible solutions would be:

- Managing focus state in each control and only process the input in the control which currently is focused

or...

- Processing the input from a centralized manager and send it only to the focused control

How do existing UI toolkits like WPF or Winforms do it? The individual controls there seem so.. decoupled, yet every control has to be aware of the currently focused one.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I have class UIControl for control, UIPanel and UIForm based on UIControl and an interfce IFocusable. If control is IFocusable, it can have input focus. If control is panel it can manage focus for his child controls. You can have one active form or update few in same time, but inside each form you have only one focused control. If this control is element container, it also has only one focused control. When user perss a key only focused control (is the ever is any) wil be notified.

I don't want to cut-out parts of code. If you want, you can see whole [sources](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/utils/src/747965a9b740/GameHelper/Graphics2D/UI/General/?at=master).